# How to repair the voids in this stone wall

Tags: walls, stone

[image]I have a stone wall and steps in my yard that have voids that need patching
What is the best way to fill these holes 
Is there some type of cement that can be used or some other material to fill the cracks and voids that may have once had stones in them
Thanks for your help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43lAy.jpg)

[image: 1[![][2]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nog2K.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Standard mortar mix will work well for this. Be aware that it will become quite a bit brighter or lighter in color when dry than the old mortar .

Comment: You can add mortar mix coloring to match colors. Make sure it’s “exterior” mortar mix...

Comment: Yes colors can be added but this is even tougher than matching paint colors in my opinion, I have found it is best to etch the surface and repoint but since this is a small area it will be tough if not covering the entire area.